# Using itertools groupby, create groups of elements, if ANY key is same in each element

Tags: python, string, group-by, python-itertools

Given a list of strings, how to group them if any value is similar?

```
inputList = ['w', 'd', 'c', 'm', 'w d', 'm c', 'd w', 'c m', 'o', 'p']

desiredOutput = [['d w', 'd', 'w', 'w d',], ['c', 'c m', 'm', 'm c'], ['o'], ['p']]
```

How to sort a list properly by first, next, and last items?

My sorting attempt:

```
groupedList = sorted(inputList, key=lambda ch: [c for c in ch.split()])
```

Output:

```
['c', 'c m', 'd', 'd w', 'm', 'm c', 'o', 'p', 'w', 'w d']
```

Desired output:

```
['c', 'c m', 'm c', 'm', 'd', 'd w', 'w', 'w d', 'o', 'p']
```

My grouping attempt:

```
b = sorted(g, key=lambda elem: [i1[0] for i1 in elem[0].split()]) # sort by all first characters
b = groupby(b, key=lambda elem: [i1[0] in elem[0].split()[:-1] for i1 in elem[0].split()[:-1]])
b = [[item for item in data] for (key, data) in b]
```

Output:

```
[[('c winnicott', 3), ('d winnicott', 2)], [('d w winnicott', 2), ('w d winnicott', 1)], [('w winnicott', 1)]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[('c winnicott', 3)], [('d winnicott', 2), ('d w winnicott', 2), ('w d winnicott', 1), ('w winnicott', 1)]]
```

Comment: What should be the result of `inputList = ["m", "d", "w d", "m c", "c d"]` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely `desiredOutput = [["m", "d", "w d", "m c", "c d"]]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely any though? I tried also `paired = { c:{c} for c in data }
for a,b in combinations(data,2): if not initialsMatch(a,b): continue; 
    paired[a].add(b)
    paired[b].add(a)  
groups    = list()
ungrouped = set(data)
while ungrouped:
    bestGroup = {}
    for i in ungrouped:
        g = paired[i] & ungrouped
        for c in g.copy():g &= paired[c] 
        if len(g) > len(bestGroup):bestGroup = g
    ungrouped -= bestGroup
    groups.append(bestGroup)
return groups`, Output is `[{'w', 'd w', 'd w w'}, {'o'}, {'c'}, {'d'}]`, but {'d'} should be in the first group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with the bubble sort algorithm.

```
def bubbleSort(arr):
n = len(arr)
swapped = False

for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(0, n-i-1):
        
        g1 = arr[j][0].split()
        g2 = arr[j + 1][0].split()
        
        if any([k > l for k in g1] for l in g2):

            swapped = True
            arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
            
            if any(s in g2 for s in g1):
                arr[j].extend(arr[j + 1])
                arr[j + 1] = ['-']
     
    if not swapped:
        return arr
    
arr = [a for a in arr if a[0]!='-']
return arr

inputList = ['w', 'd', 'c', 'm', 'w d', 'm c', 'd w', 'c m', 'o', 'p']
#inputList = ["m", "d", "w d", "m c", "c d"]

inputList = [[n] for n in inputList]

print(bubbleSort(inputList))
```

Output:

```
[['p'], ['o'], ['c m', 'm c', 'c', 'm'], ['d w', 'w d', 'w', 'd']]
```